# About fixed effects in DiD

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

Why do we need to control state-fixed effects in a Difference in Difference model? If we are comparing the difference in the change between post and pre-periods, then the fixed effects are naturally canceled out. Did I miss something?